# Get cookie in TestCafe

Tags: testing, cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

right now I'm using testcafe for automation test,
right now I want to separate function and UI and after I run function, I want to save that cookie and in UI I only need use that UI (Example login successfully in function and use that for UI, so don't need right code to login to system in UI)
I have reading document but not clearly understand what need to do, so anyone have know or experience in that please help me

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand your case. `Testcafe` tests are executed separately from one another, which means that cookies set in one test won't exist in another.
To reuse login information, you can use [`Role`](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402845/guides/intermediate-guides/authentication):

```js
import { Role } from 'testcafe';

const role = Role('http://example.com/login', async t => {
    await t
        .typeText('#login', 'TestUser')
        .typeText('#password', 'testpass')
        .click('#sign-in');
});

fixture `My Fixture`
    .page `http://example.com`;

test('My test', async t => {
    await t.useRole(role);
    //..
});
```